# Multiple QR Code reader in iOS

Tags: ios, qr-code, zxing

Currently I'm trying to develop multiple QR Code reader for iOS. 
I'm using ZXing with ZXQRCodeMultiReader to do my work.

What I've done is I simply add ZXMultipleBarcodeReader protocol in ZXCapture and add this code inside AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate :

```
NSArray* hasil ;
      hasil = [self.readers decodeMultiple:bitmap hints:self.hints error:&error];
      int arrayCount = [hasil count];
      NSLog(@"count = %d\n",arrayCount);
      for (int i=0; i<arrayCount; i++) {
          ZXResult * result = [hasil objectAtIndex:i];
          if (result) {
              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                  [self.delegate captureResult:self result:result];
              });
          }
      }
```

Instead of reading multiple QR Code the count result is 0.
Does anyone have the some issue with the solutions.

Thank you

Comment: I have the same issue